# No way to export video: h264 (ai56 / 0x36356961) FCP only?

Tags: video, video-processing, video-encoding

I have to give up on this and turn to you.

Got several videos for editing that use this codec Video: h264 (ai56 / 0x36356961). I can read that using ffmpeg, it´s one of the channels of the .mov file.

None of the usual suspects can read it: iMovie, QuickTime, VLC, ffmpeg, Perian, .... Nothing.

I have the impression this codec can *only* be used inside Final Cut Pro. Am I right?

Here is the smallest one Video:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4234369/00101W.mov

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the codec, you can decode and play the file.  The ai56 4cc is the [Calibrated{Q} AVC Intra codec](http://calibratedsoftware.com/QAVCIntra.asp).  It seems straight forward to use this codec in QuickTime, but probably will require significant effort (as it contact the vendor and code something special) to get it to work with any other software, including your own.  It seems that the only application that has built-in support for ai56 is FinalCut 6.